# Script to find old files & write list, then delete old files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

So i started with this

```
find /path-to-directory -type f -mtime +60 -exec ls -l {} \; > /path-to-directory/filenames.txt
find /path-to-directory -mtime +60 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

it gives me the list of files older than 60 days, but i want the txt file to show the files in order
from oldest to newest, i don't care if the order is reversed honestly but i can't seem to get the context correct

also would i need to keep  `-type f` on the `-exec rm -f` or would it be implied

the goal is to have a record of deleted files. i would love to see if i could get the variable of the directory to match the name of the text file.

Comment: I couldn't understand `i would love to see if i could get the variable of the directory to match the name of the text file.` can you elaborate a little?

Comment: lets say the the path is /volumes/disk/folder1/ - i would like the text file to match "folder1" - but i would love to be able to run the find command on /volumes/disk/ - and have text files created for each sub folder the command encounters- but I'm probably overthinking this.

Comment: in that case, you could loop over the directories and run this command in a loop with that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want the txt file to show the files in order from oldest to newest

Try using `ls -ltr` with `xargs`

```
find /path-to-directory -type f -mtime +60 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltr > /path-to-directory/filenames.txt
```

---

> also would i need to keep -type f on the -exec rm -f or would it be
>   implied

You would need to specify `-type f` if you wish to delete only files. else it will delete directories also.

Answer (score 1):

> but i want the txt file to show the files in order from oldest to
>   newest

```
find /path-to-directory -type f -mtime +60 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort
```

would return you the list of files in the desired order.  However, it'd contain an additional field (seconds  since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT).  In order to remove the additional field, you could say:

```
find /path-to-directory -type f -mtime +60 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort | cut -d' ' -f2
```

---

> also would i need to keep `-type f` on the `-exec rm -f` or would it be
>   implied

No, you'd need to retain that, else `find` would also return directories.

Comment: from what i see - the time stamp is unreadable= 1378995879 /path-to-file/filename.file   - i was looking for something close to 'ls -gt' as the output -but that syntax didn't work in what i had before

Comment: @user2983956 I'm not sure by what you mean by _unreadable_.  It's [number of seconds since 1970](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: sorry by unreadable i mean the timestamp isn't like this > Jul 16  2012

Comment: @user2983956 You could always pipe the output to `cut -d' ' -f2-` to remove the _unreadable_ part.  That wouldn't affect the sort order, i.e. the output would still be sorted.